# VBA Copy column data to last row of different column, do for multiple columns, loop through all worksheets do same

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to copy data from Column F (F2:F) then paste into first empty row of Column D.

Then do same for Column G (G2:G), paste to first empty row of E.

Data from H paste to (new first empty row of D).

Data from I paste to (new first empty row of E).... Through Column M

Needs to Loop through all Worksheets in Workbook and do the exact same thing.

Problem: "Syntax Error" on all the lines:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(“F2:F” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(“D” & pasteLastrowD)
```

They are all hilighted in red

I think that my problem is that I don't know how the naming convention for    Active.Sheet

Code so far:

```
Sub Doit()
Dim ws As Worksheet


For Each ws In Worksheets


copyLastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    pasteLastrowD = ActiveSheet.Range(“D” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ActiveSheet.Range(“F2:F” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(“D” & pasteLastrowD)

    pasteLastrowE = ActiveSheet.Range(“E” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

          ActiveSheet.Range(“G2:G” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(“E” & pasteLastrowE)

    pasteLastrowD = ActiveSheet.Range(“D” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ActiveSheet.Range(“H2:H” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(“D” & pasteLastrowD)

    pasteLastrowE = ActiveSheet.Range(“E” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

          ActiveSheet.Range(“I2:I” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(“E” & pasteLastrowE)

    pasteLastrowD = ActiveSheet.Range(“D” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ActiveSheet.Range(“J2:J” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(“D” & pasteLastrowD)

    pasteLastrowE = ActiveSheet.Range(“E” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

          ActiveSheet.Range(“K2:K” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(“E” & pasteLastrowE)

     pasteLastrowD = ActiveSheet.Range(“D” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ActiveSheet.Range(“L2:L” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(“D” & pasteLastrowD)

     pasteLastrowE = ActiveSheet.Range(“E” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

          ActiveSheet.Range(“M2:M” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(“E” & pasteLastrowE)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have a different style of quotation marks in all lines but the first?

Comment: Yes I think you need to change the quotes to normal ones (Shift+2). Also in your loop you are only ever referencing the active sheet, which won't change, whereas you should be referencing ws.

Comment: @SJR can you explain this in more detail please?
I'm changing the quotation marks to see if that helps.

Comment: I think that you were stating that I should change all "ActiveSheet" to "ws" correct? I did that however now I'm getting a Compile Error and it's highlighting the colon in **F2:F**

    `ws.Range(“F2:F” & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ws.Range(“D” & pasteLastrowD)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re my comment above, have just amended the first couple but hopefully you get the idea. You need to fully reference all range/cell references. You do also need to change the quotes though.

```
Sub Doit()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

copyLastrow = ws.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    pasteLastrowD = ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws.Range("F2:F" & copyLastrow).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("D" & pasteLastrowD)

'etc
```

Comment: So apparently "" is different from “”
I don't know how I got the curvy ones in there (fixed the syntax error).
However I'm getting this error message:
Run-time error '1004' 
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed
@SJR

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Doit()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            For Each cell In .Range("F2:M2")
                .Range(cell, .Cells(.Rows.Count, cell.Column).End(xlUp).Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, cell.Column Mod 2)
            Next cell
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: @AlexRoss, did you try this?